# Document.SaveAs method withoud password?

Tags: c#, office-interop

I want to save as a document without a password. The method SaveAs 4. and 6. parameters 
Password --> A password string for opening the document. (See Remarks below.)
WritePassword --> A password string for saving changes to the document. (See Remarks below.)
If I use the object missing = string.Empty and object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value lines the document saved corrupted and it can not be opened. What to do to save as the document without password. Please help

```
object FileName = RIS_CLIENT.Properties.Settings.Default.DownloadPath + "\\" + m_docFileName + ".docm";
                object FileFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled;
                object LockComments = false;
                object AddToRecentFiles = false;
                object ReadOnlyRecommended = false;
                object EmbedTrueTypeFonts = false;
                object SaveNativePictureFormat = true;
                object SaveFormsData = false;
                object SaveAsAOCELetter = false;
                object missing = "pass";
              //object missing = String.Empty;
              //object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;  


                objWinWordControl.document.SaveAs(ref FileName, ref FileFormat, ref LockComments, ref missing,
                    ref AddToRecentFiles, ref missing, ref ReadOnlyRecommended, ref EmbedTrueTypeFonts,
                    ref SaveNativePictureFormat, ref SaveFormsData, ref SaveAsAOCELetter);
```

Comment: Did you try passing in `null` instead?

Comment: yes, it throws exception

Comment: Have you tried doc.Save() method intead

Comment: I need to change file name, I can't use it

Comment: If Save works would it be possible to copy the file to new location and then open it?

Comment: Save method opens the SaveAS dialog to the user. I don't want this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sanatpalia/ConvertDocToBlob02152008144307PM/ConvertDocToBlob.aspx), `System.Reflection.Missing.Value` is the correct way of specifying missing values, but you say that does not work.

I also found [another link](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/dotnet/soa/Easily-utilise-Microsoft-Word-functionality-in-your-NET-application/0,339028399,339198903,00.htm) which is using `System.Type.Missing`, so you may wish to try this approach.

Edit: actually, it appears that `Type.Missing` is actually just `Missing.Value` in disguise, so if the latter is not working, neither will the former.